# ORACLE Date comparison issue - confused

Tags: sql, oracle, date, to-date

I have the table that has a record with the value `23-JUL-13` for `contact_date` (Date type).

I tried to run this query:

```
select * from mytable
 where contact_date >= to_date('25-JUL-2012', 'dd-MON-yyyy')
```

I was expecting the above record to be returned.

Anything wrong here? Confused!

Comment: Can you confirm if the date in your table is indeed 23-jul-2013. It could be 23-jul-1913 as well.

Comment: I just see the date as `23-JUL-13`. Is there a way to see the full date?

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3721

Comment: `select to_char(contact_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') mydate from mytable`

Comment: @KevinRave, Use `select to_char(contact_date,'dd-mon-yyyy') from mytable`.

Comment: @alfasin, .. Lol! I think you are right. I see `23-07-0013` with to_char.

Comment: @KevinRave a good catch by  Ramblin' Man (I don't deserve the credit ;) )

Comment: Well, the credit goes to @Ramblin' Man

Comment: @Ramblin' Man. Please post this as an answer for me to accept.